# Spring boot application external property file loading

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

My Spring boot application is using an external jar which is loading a file abc.properties. But when I run my application using java -jar  its not able to find file. its trying to find the file in the file:/.jar!/BOOT-INF/classes!/abc.properties

I have kept the abc.properties file in the same level where I have kept the jar.

Can anyone please suggest me how to fix this issue.

Comment: Its code is probably incorrect. But you haven't posted its code...

Comment: Please post example of the code which consumes the property file.

Answer (score 1):

To add different files you can use the spring.config.location properties which takes a comma-separated list of property files or file location (directories).

Comment: How would that help for EXTERNAL .jar?

Comment: I tried this java -jar selfcare-18.12.0.jar --spring.config.name=config.db.properties --spring.config.location=classph:/home/tdatta/workspace/tempselfcare/       but still got the error java.io.FileNotFoundException: file:/home/tdatta/workspace/tempselfcare/selfcare/selfcare-18.12.0.jar!/BOOT-INF/classes!/config.db.properties (No such file or directory)

Comment: Is this working?
java -jar  selfcare-18.12.0.jar --spring.config.location=/home/tdatta/workspace/tempselfcare/config.db.properties

Comment: nope its not working, getting error: java.io.FileNotFoundException: file:/home/tdatta/workspace/tempselfcare/selfcare/selfcare-18.12.0.jar!/BOOT-INF/classes!/config.db.properties (No such file or directory)

Comment: Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource(fileName)

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

set the following valuea in your OS

```
set SPRING_CONFIG_NAME=<name of your confif file> 
set SPRING_CONFIG_LOCATION=classpath:<location of your config file>
```

Then run your jar